# VBA Excel deselect on another tab

Tags: vba, excel

I've been roaming around but I can't seem to find a suitable answer. I have a macro that saves the data on another tab in the background depending on the time by pasting the data on that tab when I paste it on my main page. The problem is that when pasting it on a tab on the background it keeps the selection active which I personally find to look a little sloppy.

Is there a way to clear the selection on a not active tab without switching back and forth to it?

For completeness a piece of the code:

```
'Between 8 & 9
If y >= 0.334 And y <= 0.375 And Worksheets("800").Range("B1") <> DateValue(Now) Then
    Ws8.Range("A3").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Worksheets("800").Range("B1") = DateValue(Now)
    Worksheets("800").Range("C1") = TimeValue(Now)

'Between 9 & 10
ElseIf y >= 0.375 And y <= 0.417 And Worksheets("900").Range("B1") <> DateValue(Now) Then
    Ws9.Range("A3").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Worksheets("900").Range("B1") = DateValue(Now)
    Worksheets("900").Range("C1") = TimeValue(Now)
```

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `Application.`[CutCopyMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-cutcopymode-property-excel)` = False`?

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: Slightly longer answer: no. But you could turn off screen updating, go and do what you need and return before turning it on again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for `Application.CutCopyMode = False` as well as maybe selecting `Range("A1")`, maybe like below:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If y >= 0.334 And y <= 0.375 And Worksheets("800").Range("B1") <> DateValue(Now) Then
    Ws8.Range("A3").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Ws8.Select
    Ws8.Range("A1").Select
    Worksheets("800").Range("B1") = DateValue(Now)
    Worksheets("800").Range("C1") = TimeValue(Now)

'Between 9 & 10
ElseIf y >= 0.375 And y <= 0.417 And Worksheets("900").Range("B1") <> DateValue(Now) Then
    Ws9.Range("A3").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Ws9.Select
    Ws9.Range("A1").Select
    Worksheets("900").Range("B1") = DateValue(Now)
    Worksheets("900").Range("C1") = TimeValue(Now)
End If
'now select your original sheet
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 1):

After you paste the value use ↓code↓ to clear the selection.

> ```
>  Application.CutCopyMode = False
> ```

Direct value assignments are preferable over `Range.Copy` and `Range().PasteSpecial xlPasteAll`.